# After modal dismiss some functions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've got this project, a counter for a game... The idea is that when I click the "#buttonplay", it runs the jQuery function and hides the modal. That is all right, but after the modal is hidden, the function DisplayMoreInfo doesn't work... That function has to, when the user clicks on a specific game, provide more info about it.
I've got a game done without the function that runs after the #buttonplay is clicked, and it shows the info before I create a new game... But after, doesn't do anything...

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="contentplays" style="display: none">
        <button type="button" id="buttonplay" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          New Game  
        </button> <!--This button is to create a new play-->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Game</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <!--Here it goes the info of the new game-->
                        </form>
                        </p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="submitnew" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--This is the game WITHOUT the jQuery function of the #buttonplay-->
        <div class="game done" onclick="DisplayMoreInfo(NewGame);">
            <h1>NewGame</h1><br>
            <p class="info">21&sol;01&sol;2017</p><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="moreinfodone" id="NewGame" style="display: none">
            <p class="person">Player 1&colon; Pirulo</p>
            <p class="person">Player 2&colon; Zultano</p>
            <p class="person">Player 3&colon; Mengano</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
//The jQuery function
$('#submitnew').click(function () {
    $('myModal').modal('hide');
    //Some code here
});

//The function that does't work after the .modal('hide')
function DisplayMoreInfo(game) {
    $(game).toggle();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer!!!

Comment: Where the "NewGame" variable is being set?

Comment: What I think you mean is to pass the "id" to hide or show the div

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change this line of code from

```
onclick='DisplayMoreInfo(NewGame)';
```

To:

```
onclick='DisplayMoreInfo("#NewGame")';
```

### Why did not work?

You are trying to pass NewGame to the DisplayMoreInfo function, which is at that point undefined. 
Next time try to debug your code better using Chrome!

Comment: Thanks @jmmontero! But that wasn't the problem... The problem was that the modal needed to be at the bottom of the HTML right before the </body> tag... Thanks anyway!!! :)